# passport integration with loopback 4?

Tags: passport.js, loopback4

I've seen the lb3 article on integrating passport (https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb3/Third-party-login-using-Passport.html). I don't see anything similar for lb4. Is the article for lb3/passport still valid for lb4? If not, thoughts on integrating passport into lb4? (I'd really like all of passport to be available, not just 3rd-party auth.)

Comment: [This](https://medium.com/@iqbaldjulfri/role-based-authentication-with-jwt-in-loopback-4-4f9ab63daa52) tutorial worked for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [@loopback/authentication-passport](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@loopback/authentication-passport).

Document: [Using Passport-based Strategies](https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb4/Loopback-component-authentication.html#using-passport-based-strategies)